# ViewPager Fragments And CircleIndicator Re-Create Itself

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Good day, I'm having a problem regarding with `viewPager` and `CircleIndicator`. 
Every time I switch to another Activity or press the
TAB hardware keyboard panel (the switching tab between apps), and go back 
to `WelcomeActivity.java` it re-create itself - circleDots and the items in the fragments (re-create fragments). 
And also if I press the TAB hardware keyboard in the panel, and re-enter my app, it will not allow me to go back directly, it splash white then disappeared .
And if I click the icon to go back to my app, it re-create the fragments. Can you help me with this?

[image: Bug]

Here my code: **`WelcomeActivity.java`**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome_page);

    //Function Call
        assignWidgetId();
    //ViewPager for text AppIntro
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager_welcome_msg);
        circlePageIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.circle_indicator);
        setUpViewPager(mViewPager);
        circlePageIndicator.setViewPager(mViewPager);

    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int currentPage = 0;
            if(currentPage == FRAGMENT_PAGE - 1){
                currentPage = 0;
            }
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage,true);
            handler.postDelayed(runnable,DELAY_TIME_CHANGE_SLIDE);
        }
    };

    swipeTimer = new Timer();


    try{
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.yayong_welcome_video);
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        mediaPlayer.setVolume(0, 0);
        mVideoView.start();
    } catch (Exception e){
        //mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    //IF ERROR VIDEO CANNOT BE PLAYED
    mVideoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
            //wait for 1 seconds
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        //mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
            if (videoCompleted) {
                mVideoView.start();
                mediaPlayer.setVolume(0, 0);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    //IF COMPLETE REPEAT AGAIN - SILENT
    mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            videoCompleted = true;
            mVideoView.start();
            mediaPlayer.setVolume(0, 0);
        }
    });


}

public void assignWidgetId(){
    btnSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signIn);
    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signUp);
    btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(this);
    textViewForgotPass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewForgotPassword);
    textViewForgotPass.setOnClickListener(this);
    //mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.welcome_image_backup);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()){
        //GO TO LOGIN ACTIVITY
        case R.id.signIn:
            Intent intentSignIn = new Intent(WelcomePageActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentSignIn);
            finish();
            break;

        //GO TO REGISTER ACTIVITY
        case R.id.signUp:
            Intent intentSignUp = new Intent(WelcomePageActivity.this,RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentSignUp);
            finish();
            break;

        case R.id.textViewForgotPassword:
            forgotPasswordDialog();
            break;
    }
}

public void setUpViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragments(new Welcome_First_Fragment());
    adapter.addFragments(new Welcome_Fragment_Second());
    adapter.addFragments(new Welcome_Fragment_Third());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

static class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
    private static List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Adapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager){
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    public void addFragments(Fragment fragment){
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

}
```

**`WelcomeFragments.java`**

```
public class Welcome_First_Fragment extends Fragment {
RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View viewRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.welcome_fragment_first, container,false);
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) viewRoot.findViewById(R.id.welcome_about_first);

    return viewRoot;
}
```

I'm using jake wharton viewpager circleIndicator
**I solved this by using System.exit(0); every time I go back to this page, so that it will not re-create the items. I know this is not the best way. Is there any alternative way?**